# GSAP stagger animation

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrolltrigger

If an `element` has the class `.stagger` then I'm trying to execute an animation which shows the cards one by one.

In my current demo, the `cards` all fade in together. Even though I've specified a `delay`?

How can I the cards to appear one by one?

```js
  const boxes = gsap.utils.toArray('.stagger');

  boxes.forEach((box, i) => {
    const anim = gsap.fromTo(box, {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      y: 50
    }, {
      duration: 1,
      autoAlpha: 1,
      y: 0,
      delay: 0.5,
    });
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: box,
      animation: anim,
      toggleActions: 'play none none none',
      once: true,
    });
  });
```

```css
.section{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my current demo, the cards all fade in together. Even though I've specified a delay?

Each card has a `0.5s` delay, so the'll move all together.

---

Use a delay based on the current card index:

```js
delay: 0.5 + (0.5 * i)
```

So every card will be delayed with (`0.5s` + half a second for each index)

---

```js
  const boxes = gsap.utils.toArray('.stagger');

  boxes.forEach((box, i) => {
    const anim = gsap.fromTo(box, {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      y: 50
    }, {
      duration: 1,
      autoAlpha: 1,
      y: 0,
      delay: 0.5 + (0.5 * i),
    });
    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: box,
      animation: anim,
      toggleActions: 'play none none none',
      once: true,
    });
  });
```

```css
.section{
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>


<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card text-center stagger">
          Card
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```